# Not all code paths return a value when parsing csv files

Tags: c#, csv

I keep getting the following error message whenever I try to run my script - `Error 1   'AddressLookup.Form1.GetAddress(string)': not all code paths return a value`.

This occurs with the following block of code:

```
    private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String addressText = GetAddress(AddressEntry.Text);
        MessageBox.Show(addressText);
    }

    String GetAddress(String addressText)
    {
        var strLines = File.ReadLines("pca_mk_addresslist.csv");
        foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("pca_mk_addresslist.csv"))
        {
            var fields = line.Split(',');

            foreach (var field in fields)
            {
                if (field == addressText)
                    return field;
            }
            return String.Empty;
        }
    }
```

However, with the following block of code, it all works ok but whenever I try finding a result, then it returns a blank messagebox:

```
    private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String addressText = GetAddress(AddressEntry.Text);
        MessageBox.Show(addressText);
    }

    String GetAddress(String addressText)
    {
        var strLines = File.ReadLines("pca_mk_addresslist.csv");
        foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("pca_mk_addresslist.csv"))
        {
            var fields = line.Split(',');

            foreach (var field in fields)
            {
                if (field == addressText)
                    return field;
            }

        }
        return String.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: Imagine what happens if the loop never gets entered.

Comment: btw if field matches why are you returning fields[1] instead of field ? it doesn't make sense

Comment: `"it returns a blank message box"` - Well, one of the code paths in that method returns `String.Empty`.  Do you expect something other than a blank message box when displaying `String.Empty`?  Step through the code in a debugger and examine the runtime values.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're calling `File.ReadLines` multiple times on the same file, and never using the first one? That seems super wasteful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file `pca_mk_addresslist.csv` is empty, your `foreach` loop will never be entered (foreach object in an empty collection yields zero iterations). Thus, since you return only in the loop, the case of an empty file never returns anything. That's not allowed.

```
if pca_mk_addresslist.csv has any lines
    return something
else
    ?
```

You need to tell it what your *default* value should be. It might well be `null`, but you have to tell it that. It isn't the compiler's job to assume what you want your program to do. Only to make it easier for you to write it.

As for your second question, it looks like your file *is*, in fact, empty. Either that or no fields match. You might want to add in some better default text, or step through the program to discover which it is.

**Edit:**

As per comment, what you want is something more like

```
private String GetAddress(String addressText)
{
    var strLength = File.ReadAllLines("pca_mk_addresslist.csv");

    var strLines = File.ReadLines("pca_mk_addresslist.csv");
    foreach (var line in strLines)
    {
        var fields = line.Split(',');

        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            if (field == addressText)
                return field;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Haguen - Thanks, I've attempted the following but keep getting the error message http://pastebin.com/SLubtHhf

Comment: It's not that smart. Just add the contents of your `else` after, with no conditions. I'm on my phone so I can't show you, but yeah.

Comment: @methuselah I added in how it should be. But make sure you understand the code before you use it, since returning `null` does actually mean something here, and as I said, it looks like your file might actually be empty, so be ready to accept and utilize the information that `null` gives you.